# How to add more developers to my development projects

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, azure-devops, tfvc

What are the best practices and options for expanding to a small team ?

I am the only user of Visual Studio 2012 in my small company. I am using Visual Studio Online for Source Control (as I understand it, this exposes Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server Version Version 14.0.12345.23456 as a "service" (i.e. this is the cloud...there is no on-premise TFS installed). Currently, I am using a LOCAL workspace (the default) and TFVC (not GIT).

My development server runs IIS 7.5 on Win2008 R2. I logon locally to this dev server and launch VStudio 2012 Professional as an administrator. Project source code is on the local harddrive (e.g. d:\projects\projectA, etc.). I can interactively debug my web application projects and sit on a breakpoint without "disturbing" any other user or developer.

I work remotely so I use a mobile VPN with SSL to connect via Remote Desktop to the above development server (only 2 concurrent connections are supported now).

Some specific questions:

- Can another person(s) somehow "share" the above environment?
- How can developer2 and dev3 work concurrently on same project(s) as me?
- Can I simply add dev2 and dev3 logons to the admin group on the dev server?
- Would changing the TFS setting from LOCAL workspace to SERVER workspace enable team development (i.e. prevent checkout if already checked out, etc.)
- If "sharing" the above environment is possible, what would the ideal arrangement look like (e.g. each developer has own server, own Vstudio license, etc.)?

Answer (score 2):

Usually, every developer in a team has their own development machine. You create a team project in Visual Studio Online, and check in your project to this team project. When you want to dev2 and dev3 to work on this project, you can [add dev2 and dev3 in the team project](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/setup/add-team-members-vs) (Visual Studio Online provides 5 free licenses), so they can access this team project and get the project to their development machine.

Team Foundation Version Control is a centralized version control system. Typically, team members have only one version of each file on their dev machines. Historical data is maintained only on the server. Every time your team checks in their work into Visual Studio Online, you can easily audit changes and identify which user checked in a changeset.

Regarding Workspace, please check the definitions below:

> •Server workspaces: Before making changes, team members publicly check
> out files. Most operations require developers to be connected to the
> server. (In the past teams blocked more than one person from checking
> out, but this is now less common.) This system facilitates locking
> work flows.
> •Local workspaces: Each team member takes a copy of the
> latest version of the codebase with them and works offline as needed.
> Developers check in their changes and resolve conflicts as necessary.

Usually, local workspace is recommended.

More information of TFVC, you can refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181237%28v=vs.140%29.aspx